# Created a group in assets. After that images not loading (even the app icon)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Because of difficult in distinguishing between diffrent asset images, I have created a group inside assets and its working fine on simulator,

But when coming to actual device asset not loading. event my app icon was disappeared.
Below is created asset groups.

[image]

Im using Xcode 9.1 and swift 4.

Is there any way to get around this? Seems like Xcode bug.

Comment: Please check if target Membership is ticked or not in the image assets.?

Comment: yes it was automatically unchecked by Xcode I think

Comment: I have mentioned the steps in answer. If it worked for you approve that

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you solution is:

[image]

**Check whether it is ticked or not**

if it is not then tick it and it will work